# How to install/get started with MEF 2

Tags: c#, mef, mef2

I want to use MEF 2 in a project. I'm trying to [follow this guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/366583/MEF-Preview-Beginners-Guide) to get started, but I cannot seem to get even the first snippet of code to run. The `RegistrationBuilder` simply doesn't exist and I don't seem to have the `System.ComponentModel.Composition.Registration` namespace that it's supposed to be in.

All I've done is install the [Microsoft.Composition package from Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.composition). I'm able to find the classes in the [`System.Composition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.composition(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace fine, yet that doesn't seem to be enough to get started.

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2013 with .NET 4.5.1. The project is a console project (although I also tried a Windows project), although the ultimate goal is to use this in ASP.NET.

What more do I need to do to get MEF2 working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the `System.ComponentModel.Composition.Registration` assembly from the add references menu (doh).